# Entity Framework SqlQuery Nullable Fields

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework `SqlQuery`  to fetch data.

Here is the code:

```
Context.Database.SqlQuery<MyModel>("exec dbo.MySP @StartDate, @EndDate", Params.ToArray()).ToListAsync();
```

and `MyModel` class

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int? Code{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public DateTime? InsertDate { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is nullable columns turn into `Null` in all rows when there are some `Null` columns in my stored procedure result. But when I remove those `Null` columns in the stored procedure, everything work fine.

**UPDATE**: here is the stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySP] 
    @StartDate DATETIME = NULL,
    @EndDate DATETIME = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #LastUpdates (Code INT, InsertDate DATETIME)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO #LastUpdates 
        SELECT
            StoreCode,
            MAX(InsertDate)
        FROM 
            [dbo].[History]
        WHERE 
            (@StartDate IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(DAY, InsertDate, @StartDate) <= 0 )
            AND (@EndDate IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(DAY, InsertDate, @EndDate) >= 1)
        GROUP BY 
            StoreCode

    SELECT DISTINCT
        store.Name as Name,
        store.Code as Code,
        Updates.InsertDate AS InsertDate
    FROM 
        #LastUpdates AS Updates 
    RIGHT JOIN 
        [Stores] AS store ON Updates.Code = store.Code
    WHERE 
        store.IsDeleted = 0

    DROP TABLE #LastUpdates 
END
```

Comment: whats the error that you are getting or what do you want to achieve

Comment: You will need to share the sql that is in the stored procedure for us to help.

Comment: Is your intention to return null InsertDates no matter what the StartDate and EndDate are?

Comment: Can StartDate or EndDate parameters be null and if yes, what do you want in that case, to find null InsertDates only OR ignore the parameter?

Comment: @klabranche, `StartDate` and `EndDate` can be null and i want them just for fetch data in start and end date range. I added `Stored Procedure`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure need to return all properties from your model (the same name). If procedure returns any other fields and your model expects them, you will got the error.

The query returns all rows from history and that right join on stores based on conditions. If no records in stores matches, the record from history still included into recordset. You probably need INNER JOIN.

It seems like EF (at least at one point) returned null row.
So rather then selecting * you should explicitly name the columns and ensure that the PK (or some other column) is first.

Note :
I think it's almost always possible to avoid RIGHT JOIN; queries with LEFT JOIN are much easier to read and understand.

Comment: The properties appear to be right as the user states that if they remove null insertdates the query works.

Comment: @NaDeR-Star, I return all properties just like the `MyModel`

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE (@StartDate IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(DAY,InsertDate,@StartDate) <= 0 )
   AND (@EndDate IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(DAY,InsertDate,@EndDate) >= 1)
```

Does ignore your parameters when they are null.  However, this still does not handle null `InsertDates`.  `DATEDIFF` will return null for null `InsertDates`.

You need to add `(InsertDate is null) OR` to the rest of your query if you desire to return all null InsertDates.

```
WHERE (InsertDate is null) OR ((@StartDate IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(DAY,InsertDate,@StartDate) <= 0 )
   AND (@EndDate IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(DAY,InsertDate,@EndDate) >= 1))
```

You might also want to consider replacing `DATEDIFF` with normal date comparison syntax for performance reasons.  `InsertDate >= @StartDate` will be faster especially if `InsertDate` has an index on it.  I also believe this syntax makes it more clear that you are looking for `InsertDates` between these parameter dates or use the built in `between` syntax which translates it to the >= & <= syntax.

Before Adding SP SQL & answering Questions:

Without the underlying sql we are a bit blind in helping you and we would need a little more information as well.  I asked a couple of questions (above, in the question comments) that would help us understand more clearly:

That aside:

I'm assuming you are doing a range/between on the `InsertDate` against the `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`.  Since these parameters are passing in dates, null will never be found if you are doing normal range/between syntax like `InsertDate >= @StartDate` or `InsertDate between @StartDate and @EndDate` as NULL will never equal a date, only when `@StartDate` or `@EndDate` is NULL.

If you desire to return all null `InsertDates` then you have to add to your query something like:

```
select field1,field2 from table1
where (InsertDate is null) or (InsertDate >= @StartDate and InsertDate <= @EndDate)
```

If the `@StartDate` or `@EndDate` is null and you want this to mean ignore the parameter then you have to look to rewrite the underlying SQL in the Stored Procedure to handle more than just `InsertDate >= @StartDate`.

It would have to look more like `(@StartDate is null or InsertDate >= @StartDate)`.

The same would have to be done for the `@EndDate` parameter.